# How can I fetch the style of a not yet existing element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, styles

So, I want to fetch the `top` computed style of a `<div>` and put it into a variable. However, that `<div>` is not yet in the DOM. It will be appended to the DOM by a JavaScript event later (once the user triggers the `.onclick()` event).

To do that, I tried this: 
`let style = getComputedStyle(element).top;`

However, that won't work since `element` is not in the DOM yet. The following error appears if I attempt to do so:

### [image: Error]

So, how can I fetch the `top` style of a specific element even if that element isn't in the DOM yet?

Comment: You could add it to the DOM with HTML "hidden" tag. That was it wont display on page but you can its styles.

Comment: i tried that, it didn't work, still got the error. i think ill just have to work around this fact by putting the variable once the click event is fired and element has been appended to DOM. thank tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can only get the computed style of an element in the DOM, since its computed style depends on where it is, what's around it, and what styles are in place.

Instead, if you know the characteristics of the DOM element and where it will be, you can add a placeholder for it in the same place, with the same classes, etc.; then get its style, get `top` from that, then remove it. The user will never see it if you do that all in one sequence without yielding back to the event loop.

Comment: oh ok... I guess ill just have to work around it.. Thanks!